# how to read the namespaces prefix's using digester in java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I am very much new to xml parsing ,i am trying to parse an xml file using the digester parser , i have done the parsing , but how do i read the root element attributes some thing like this

I could able to read the xmlns attribute , but how to i read the xmlns:xsil, xsi:schemalocation attributes ,how do i do this?

Comment: you are a member of StackOverflow from 2 months - but I think you do not understand how the site works. you have to accept some of the 20 answers to your earlier questions - else people will not be keen to assist.

Comment: click on the tick mark to the left of the answer which seems most appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable [namespace](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/commons/digester/package-summary.html#doc.Namespace) aware parsing in Digester